# If $(X_{t})_{t\in \mathbb{R}}$ has independent increments than $X_t$ and $X_s$ are independent if $t\neq s$?

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, independence

The stochastic process $(X_{t})_{t\in \mathbb{R}}$ is said to have independent increments if for $n\in \mathbb{N}$ $t_1<t_2<\ldots < t_n$ I have that $X_{t_2}-X_{t_1}, X_{t_3}-X_{t_2},...$ are independent. But does that mean in particular that for $t\neq s \in \mathbb{R}$ we have that $X_t$ and $X_s$ are independent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, certainly not.  For example, let $X_0$ be a non-trivial random variable, and let $X_t = X_0$ for all $t$.  Then the increments are all zero, and thus independent.  But $X_0$ is not independent of itself.

Comment: Thank you! I get it